# Referencing my own command

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, labels

I'm trying make my own command for a requirements document. I'm now looking for a way to reference my requirements. This should be possible by using \ref and the later on with the hyerref package.

The returned string of the \ref command shall be the Requirement-ID (#1).

But I have no idea how to make this happen.
Could anyone please help?

Thanks & bye,
aronadaal

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\req}[2]{ %
  \begingroup%
    \textbf{#1}\label{req:#1}~#2\newline %
  \endgroup%
} %

\begin{document}


\req{MY.REQ.ID.42}{a lot of text... and so on}

Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about making a new command that wraps `\ref` in the same way that your `\req` command wraps `\label`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\req}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \textbf{#1}\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{req:#1}~#2\newline
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\req{MY.REQ.ID.42}{a lot of text... and so on}

Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I already tried "\def\@currentlabel" but I forgot to put the command between the makeat...