# Replacing # for use inside \label

Tags: characters

we currently use unique IDs inside our documents that can be extended by adding one or more tags. A tag always starts with an hash character eg. MY.REQ.ID.42#TAG1#TAG2

The following code is part of a macro that we use to generate 'nice' looking requirements:

```
\textbf{#1}\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{req:#1}
```

Together with a list where all requirements are listed, \label has problems with the # character inside.  So I'm looking for a way to get rid to the character by replacing it with something other, eg. '..' or 'HASH'.

any idea would be appreciated...

Thanks & bye, aronadaal

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\req}[2]{%
  \begingroup%
    \textbf{#1}\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{req:#1}~#2\newline
  \endgroup%
  \addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{#1}%
} %

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=requirement, %
  types=requirements, %
  name=Anforderung, %
  listname={List of Requirements} %
]{lor}
\setuptoc{lor}{chapteratlist}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\req{MY.REQ.ID.42}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...}

\req{MY.REQ.ID.43\#BROKEN}{this requirement is broken,...}

Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42} on page~\pageref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42}

\listofrequirements

\end{document}
```

part of the log file:

```
(./req_test.aux
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\#
l.5 ...REQ.ID.43\#BROKEN}{{MY.REQ.ID.43\#BROKEN}{1}}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.


LaTeX Warning: Label `req:MY.REQ.ID.43\#BROKEN' multiply defined.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
\#
l.5 ...REQ.ID.43\#BROKEN}{{MY.REQ.ID.43\#BROKEN}{1}}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I follow what you mean. Could you post a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/11002) please?

Comment: sure, here we go.

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes sense to me. I'll post a solution soon I hope.

Comment: Follow up to [Referencing my own command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236313)

Comment: Sorry, I think I give up. `#` is just the worst choice for a char in anything. You can make it working, but it would mean redefining everything in LaTeX. (Or find someone who's a better TeXpert than me).

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you used `\#` in the `\req` parameter. If this is not an issue, you can simply redefine locally its meaning when you generate the label. For instance, you can replace `\label{req:#1}` by `{\def\#{REPLACEMENT}\xdef\lbl{req:#1}}\label{\lbl}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hashtag}{\#}
\newcommand{\req}[2]{%

\begingroup%
\textbf{#1}{\def\@currentlabel{#1}{\def\#{::}\xdef\lbl{req:#1}}\label{\lbl}}~#2\newline%
\endgroup%
\addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{#1}%
} %

\DeclareNewTOC[%
type=requirement, %
types=requirements, %
name=Anforderung, %
listname={List of Requirements} %
]{lor}
\setuptoc{lor}{chapteratlist}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\req{MY.REQ.ID.42}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...}%
\req{MY.REQ.ID.42\#WORKING}{this requirement is broken,...}

Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42} on page~\pageref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42}

Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42::WORKING} on page~\pageref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42::WORKING}

\listofrequirements

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Well, I have to use the `\#` inside the document because there will be errors like (_! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode._) instead.

Your code looks quite simple and works properly.

Answer (score 2):

Because the simple solution isn't here till now, I put it:

```
\protected\edef\#{\string#}
```

Comment: It would be better saying also *where* one should put this code.

Comment: IMHO, this is clear: in the area where another definitions are:). For example, before `\DeclareNewTOC`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this works, but it is a very dirty trick. I hope I'll later manage to comment the code. One thing is sure: it's extremely fragile (and impossible to robustify).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter
\def\req#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\#=13
    \makehashexcl
    \edef\aron@do@label{\noexpand\label{req:\scantokens{#1\noexpand}}}%
    \makehashhash
    {\bfseries\scantokens{#1\noexpand}}%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\scantokens{#1\noexpand}}%
    \aron@do@label
    ~#2\newline
    \edef\aron@do@lor{\noexpand\addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{\scantokens{#1\noexpand}}}%
    \aron@do@lor
  \endgroup%
}

\def\refreq#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\#=13
    \makehashexcl
    \edef\aron@do@{\noexpand#1{req:\scantokens{#2\noexpand}}}%
    \aron@do@
  \endgroup
}

\catcode`\#=13
\def\makehashexcl{\def##{!}}
\def\makehashhash{\def##{\char35 }}
\makehashhash
\catcode`\#=6

\DeclareRobustCommand\HASH{\char35 }

\makeatother


\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=requirement,
  types=requirements,
  name=Anforderung,
  listname={List of Requirements}
]{lor}
\setuptoc{lor}{chapteratlist}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\req{MY.REQ.ID.42}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...}

\req{MY.REQ.ID.43#BROKEN}{this requirement is broken,...}

Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42} on page~\pageref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42}

Please have a look at \refreq\ref{MY.REQ.ID.43#BROKEN} on page~\refreq\pageref{MY.REQ.ID.43#BROKEN}

\listofrequirements

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think the code of @TonioElGringo will solve my problem. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Here I use the `\convertchar` macro of the `stringstrings` package to change *all* occurances of `\#` into `?`, and use that in the label.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\req}[2]{%
  \convertchar[q]{#1}{\#}{?}%
  \begingroup%
    \textbf{#1}\def\@currentlabel{#1}\label{req:\thestring}~#2\newline
  \endgroup%
  \addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{#1}%
} %

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=requirement, %
  types=requirements, %
  name=Anforderung, %
  listname={List of Requirements} %
]{lor}
\setuptoc{lor}{chapteratlist}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\req{MY.REQ.ID.42}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...}

\req{MY.REQ.ID.43\#BROKEN\#}{this requirement is broken,...}

Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42} on page~\pageref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42}

Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.43?BROKEN?} on 
  page~\pageref{req:MY.REQ.ID.43?BROKEN?}

\listofrequirements

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the result looks a bit odd. The Req-ID is now duplicated... once with `?` and once with `#`.

Comment: @aronadaal  Please see revision.  I'm still not quite sure if I've captured your intent.