# Discretionary hyphens for words in dot-notation

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, discretionary

we're working on a technical document with some special requirement identifier, which use a dot-notation. For example:

```
FRQ.SW.MOD.GUI.1
FRQ.DATA.LOG.OUT.PRINT.1
```

As you might expect we get a lot of `overfull box` messages and theses "words" get not split by the hyphenation mechanism.

So I'm looking for another solution. Is there a way defining a discretionary-rule or something else to get these words wrapped? We don't want to use something like `\url`. The user experience should be smooth as possible.

Thx, aronadaal

This question is a follow up to [Replacing # for use inside \label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236452/replacing-for-use-inside-label)

Comment: why not `\url` don't you have some command already wrapping these identifiers for font change at least, or do you just use the text font with no markup? (I posted an answer suggesting `\url` then noticed you said not that, so it is deleted, but it seems like the right answer to me:-)

Comment: you have tagged this luatex, although you do not mention that in the text, does that mean a lua-only solution is acceptable?

Comment: in your linked example all such words appear inside `\req` so why not just define `\req` using `url` package so that it breaks at the `.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `url` package and

```
\path|FRQ.DATA.LOG.OUT.PRINT.1|
```

and it will allow breaking at `.`

You could define a command with a different name if needed, see the url package documentation.

Adding this to your example from the linked question, and setting up `@` as a safer way to input # gives

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{url}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\req}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \textbf{\url{#1}}%
    \addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{\protect\url{#1}}%
    \def\@currentlabel{\protect\url{#1}}\label{req:#1}~#2\par
   \endgroup  
}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=requirement, %
  types=requirements, %
  name=Anforderung, %
  listname={List of Requirements} %
]{lor}
\setuptoc{lor}{chapteratlist}

\def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\.}
\mathchardef\UrlBigBreakPenalty=50
\let\oldUrlSpecials\UrlSpecials
\def\UrlSpecials{\oldUrlSpecials\do\@{\texttt\#}}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\req{MY.REQ.ID.42}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...}

\req{MY.REQ.ID.43@BROKEN}{this requirement is broken,...}

xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx 
xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx 
Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42} on page~\pageref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42}

x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x
Please have a look at \ref{req:MY.REQ.ID.43@BROKEN} on page~\pageref{req:MY.REQ.ID.42}


\listofrequirements

\end{document}
```